# How to add MapServer layer to Leaflet?

Tags: mapserver, leaflet

I have a layer in PostGIS in epsg:4326. Put in MapServer:

```
MAP
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    EXTENT 60.0 56.0 61.2 57.4701
    SIZE 800 600
    OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "png"
        DRIVER        GD/PNG
        IMAGEMODE     PC256
        TRANSPARENT   ON
    END
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3857"
    END
    LAYER
        NAME "boundary"
        CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
        CONNECTION "user=postgres password=postgres dbname=ekb_1 host=localhost"
        DATA "the_geom from bige"
        TYPE POLYGON
        CLASS
            COLOR 200 120 123
        END
    END
END
```

Now I add it to a Leaflet map:

```
            var map = new L.Map('map',{
                center: new L.LatLng(56.8391677245,60.7011796115)
                ,minZoom: 12
                ,maxZoom: 20
                ,zoom: 14
                ,zoomAnimation: true,
                measureControl: true,
            });

            var nexrad = L.tileLayer.wms('http://127.0.0.1/map/?map=/srv/www/localhost/public_html/map/ekb_test.map&mode=map', {
           layers:'boundary',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
            attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
        });
        map.addLayer(nexrad);
```

And see multiple layer images on map. What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**

There is my  /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mapserv -v output:

```
MapServer version 6.2.1 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG SUPPORTS=PROJ
 SUPPORTS=GD SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO 
SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER 
SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT 
SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS 
SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

Comment: Please check following link (need translate to English) http://profmarcello.blogspot.com/2013/06/configuracao-de-layers-wms-do-mapserver.html

Comment: Here is my wms server config http://dotrem.blogspot.ru/2014/04/simple-wms-server-using-mapserver.html

Comment: `mode=map` should be removed if you want a WMS connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "And see multyple layer images on map" but for a start you are creating a Leaflet WMS tile layer, without having a WMS service setup in your mapserver configuration. See [docs](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html) and the example in @sunil link for more info.

Comment: Thanks to you and @Sunil. Its first time i see Mapserver WMS configuration. Your link really usefull.